# Simulate predicted probabilities after a logistic regression

Tags: logistic, stata, simulation, propensity-scores

I'm generating predicted probabilities (propensity scores) in Stata using the predict command. The basic structure of my code looks like this:

```
logit depvar indepvars
predict ps               // Gives Pr(depvar = 1 | indepvars)
predict s, stdp          // Gives the standard error of the prediction
```

The predicted probabilities/propensity scores are obviously estimates with an error distribution around them. What I would like to do is use the results obtained from the  `predict` command to simulate some plausible values for the predicted probabilities/propensity scores. Any advice on how I might proceed?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: See here: http://www.stata.com/support/faqs/statistics/prediction-confidence-intervals/

Comment: This is useful. But how do I get from a CI around the predicted probability to taking draws from the underlying distribution? My goal is to simulate some plausible values.

Comment: You can use the Clarify package in stata to do this: http://simonfink.wordpress.com/2013/03/20/clarify-for-dummies-like-me-part-1/